# When to Eliminate One to One Relationship

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, one-to-one, erd

When I design data model using ERD, sometimes I find one to one relationship in my database. For example, activity has schedule and every activity can only have one schedule. I find it make more sense to separate activity and schedule with their own tables, so I made activity and schedule as a separate entity. My reason is because we don't know what will happen in the future, requirements may change and one day, maybe one activity can have more than one schedule.

My question is, can someone please give me a sample case where there is a strong reason to merge one to one relationship as one entity?

Please don't give opinion, **I want answers with reference**. Thank you very much.

Comment: You shouldn't really worry about one to one relationships. Its many to many relationships you want to remove

Comment: @RyanGadsdon, as far as I know, many to many relationship will always generate new table. Is that what you mean by removing many to many relationship?

Comment: Yes, you would create a new table to remove a many to many relationship. But i dont understand why you would want to remove a one to one relationship.

Comment: @RyanGadsdon, my co-worker told me to merge the one to one relationship table as one but, I insist that it should be kept separated for the sake readability and scalability.